# Nomethod error when trying to make rr mock stubs work

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rr

I am setting up a project and have been trying to make rr mocks work but I am getting nomethod error. I have tried moving the required method as well but nothing works. This is my [repo](https://github.com/saadbinakhlaq/test-rr)

```
$ rspec spec/views
F

Failures:

  1) home/show.html.haml
     Failure/Error: stub(view).user { user }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::HomeShowHtmlHaml:0x007fc245188f08>
     # ./spec/views/home/show.html.haml_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
     # /Users/saadbinakhlaq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have tried whatever was mentioned here [rr](https://github.com/rr/rr)

```
# Gemfile
group :test do
  gem 'rr', require: false
end

# test helper
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'your/test/framework'  # if you are using something other than MiniTest / Test::Unit
require 'rr'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working finally, I used `gem 'rr',  '1.1.2'` instead of `1.2.0` which got auto installed when running bundler without the gem version.